# Is the dimension of a vector space the same as the number of linearly independent vectors of the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the dimension of a vector space the same as the number of linearly independent vectors of the vector space? 
If $\text{dim}N(A)=6$, then is the number of linearly independent vectors in the null space always $6$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linear independence is a property of a **set** of vectors, not of a single vector.  You can't say "v is a linearly independent vector" - what is it independent of ? - and if you interpret this to mean "{v} is a linearly independent set of vectors" then that is trivially true for any non-zero v. Language is sometimes confusing here, as people talk about "a set of linearly independent vectors" when they more strictly mean "a linearly independent set of vectors"

Having said that, then if you have a linearly independent set of vectors *and* this set is a [spanning set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) for A then the number of vectors in that set is always the dimension of A - in fact, that is how the dimension of A is defined. Such a set is called a "basis" for A.

It not completely obvious that every possible basis of A has the same size - this is something that has to be proved. And there are some fine points that have to be taken care of to extend this to infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

No, the dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of its basis.

In $\Bbb R^3$ the vectors

$$\begin{pmatrix}
n\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\ \text{and} \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
n\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

are linearly independent for all $n \neq 0$ but $\dim(\Bbb R^3) = 3$